# Why mmap a file result in using more memory than file's size?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, mmap

I am experimenting with `mmap` and came with the following sample code:

```
    int main() {

    int fd;
    char *filename = "/home/manu/file";
    struct stat statbuf;
    int i = 0;
    char c = *(filename);

    // Get file descriptor and file length
    fd = open(filename, O_RDONLY);
    if (fd == -1) {
        perror("fopen error");
    }
    if (fstat(fd, &statbuf) < 0) {
        perror("fstat error");
    }
    printf("File size is %ld\n", statbuf.st_size);

    // Map the file
    char* mmapA = (char*) mmap(NULL, statbuf.st_size, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE,
            fd, 0);
    if (mmapA == MAP_FAILED) {
        perror("mmap error");
        return 1;
    }

    // Touch all the mapped pages
    while (i < statbuf.st_size) {
        c = mmapA[i];
        i++;
    }
    c++;

    // Close file descriptor
    if (close(fd) == -1) {
        perror("close");
        return 1;
    }

    //Unmap file
    munmap(mmapA, statbuf.st_size);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The file size is 137948 bytes = 134,7 kilobytes.
To inspect program's memory I am using top, mainly the RES and VIRT columns. I am looking for these values at three different places:

1. just before the `mmap` call
2. just after the `mmap` call
3. after having read all the mapped memory to have the file's effectively loaded into main memory (after page faults)

The value reported by top are

1. VIRT = 1828 RES = 244
2. VIRT = 1964 RES = 248
3. VIRT = 1964 RES = 508

1964 - 1828 = 136, I guess in kilobytes and thus perfectly match the file's size.

But I can't understand the RES difference of 508 - 248 = 260 .. Why is it different from virtual memory size and file size ?

Comment: The OS is coded to be optimal for either the most common uses, or the typical uses for the customer that shouted loudest - it does a lot of things that may not make sense for your use. Do you actually care?

Comment: @MartinBeckett No I don't care at all ;-) it's just for learning purpose and I am curious.

Comment: well you could always read the source;-) My guess is that it always reserves a certain memory above the mmap in case it expands - even though here you open read only. But I don't know so I haven't added this as an answer

Comment: @MartinBeckett The problem of reading the source here, is that I don't know where to read it ? In my opinion (but I am not sure at all) it may not be in the mmap implementation (because it effectively map the requested amount of virtual memory) but it the code handling the page faults when reading. Isn't it ?

Comment: it will also be so complex for such a core system level function that it will be unreadable, hence the " ;-) ". Pageing and mmap are normally very closely linked, that's why mmap is so good - it's using the OS page swapping system which is normally very well optimised

Comment: Side-note. Instead of touching each byte, use `sysconf(_SC_PAGE_SIZE)`; typically 4096: `i += pagesize;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing is certain: the results depend on the state of the system and not only on the running application. On my machine, the increase in RES was 136 kB the first two times I run the program, but the subsequent runs didn't involve any increase at all - probably the OS already had the whole file in cache. Interestingly, the values themeselves differed significantly between runs. In the first run the jump in RES was from 344 to 480 kB, but the latter runs had a RES value of 348 kB all the time. There was a similar change in SHR: a jump of 136 kB first time and no change later.

I was able to force the original case (with the 136 kB jump) at will by overwriting the file which is later mapped with with zeros using `dd` before running the app.

I looked at `pmaps` output but it was exactly the same in both cases and didn't change after the call to `mmap()`.

I can't reproduce the oversized RES jump here, but here's what you can do. Suppose your binary is compiled as `a.out`. Insert a 10 second sleep right after the `mmap()` and another 10 second sleep just before `munmap()`. This gives a time window to dump interesting information. We will read from `/proc` which exactly files are resident in memory. In order to do this, open up two tabs in your terminal, in one run

```
./a.out
```

and then immediately in the other tab:

```
for ((i=0;i<4;i++)); do cat /proc/$(ps -fe | egrep '[a]\.out' | awk '{print $2}')/smaps > smaps.$i; sleep 5; done
```

This will create 4 snapshots of the program's map states in four separate files. The difference between one of the consecutively numbered snapshot should show what changes during the surge in RES size. On my machine during a sample run, the difference was between snapshots 1 and 2, and the change was [note I changed the name of mapped file but it's not important here]:

```
user@machine:~$ diff -u smaps.{1,2}
--- smaps.1     2012-04-19 00:01:46.000000000 +0200
+++ smaps.2     2012-04-19 00:01:51.000000000 +0200
@@ -84,13 +84,13 @@
 MMUPageSize:           4 kB
 b782f000-b7851000 r--p 00000000 08:05 429102     /tmp/tempfile
 Size:                136 kB
-Rss:                   0 kB
-Pss:                   0 kB
+Rss:                 136 kB
+Pss:                 136 kB
 Shared_Clean:          0 kB
 Shared_Dirty:          0 kB
-Private_Clean:         0 kB
+Private_Clean:       136 kB
 Private_Dirty:         0 kB
-Referenced:            0 kB
+Referenced:          136 kB
 Swap:                  0 kB
 KernelPageSize:        4 kB
 MMUPageSize:           4 kB
```

What happens is exactly what should: the mapped file is initially not resident at all and 136 kB are resident later on.

On your system, the diff should lead you to the source of the additional change in RES - you should be able to find out the name of the other file(s) whose `Rss` value changes. Some entries are not files, but other memory areas, for example you may find markers such as `[heap]` and `[stack]`. This should also prove or disprove nos' suggestion about system libraries being loaded and stack usage growing.

Comment: Many thanks for this complete answer. Using smaps, as for you, I only have a difference of 136 kb in the RSS of the file I memory mapped. Thus I am know wondering what does top or ps (I was previously using) report exactly under the RSS label.

Comment: `top` is a part of [`procps`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/procps/) package and it takes its data from `/proc`, too, but apparently from a different place than `smaps`. If you dig into the [code](http://procps.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/procps/procps/) you will probably be able to find out the exact source of the RES column in `top`.